# Find $n,d$ for $U_d(n)$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

We know that $U(n)=\{r\in \mathbb{N}: 1\leqslant r\leqslant n, (r,n)=1\}$ is a multiplciative group under the binary operation multiplication modulo $n$. For any positive divisor $d$ of $n$ , the following
$$U_d(n)=\{x\in U(n): x\equiv 1[d]\}$$
is a subgroup of $U(n)$.

Now suppose that for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and a positive divisor $d$ of $n$, we are given
$$U_d(n)=\{1,8,22,29,43,64,71,92\}$$
How to find such $n$ and $d$?

Here is what I did so far.

Clearly $x\equiv 1[d]$ means $x=1+dt$ for some integer $t$. Here for $x=1,8,22,29,43,64,71,92$ we have
$$dt\in \{0,7,21,28,42,63,70,91\}$$
As gcd of these integers is 7, we have $d=7$ and so $U_d(n)$ becomes $U_7(n)$ now.

Again, $n$ is a multiple of $d$ means $n$ is a multiple of 7 now. Moreover, $U_m(mn)\simeq U(\frac{mn}{m})=U(n)$ iff $(m,n)=1$.

Here I got stuck. What are the steps remaining?

Comment: To determine $n$, look at which numbers of the form $7k + 1$ do not belong to $U_d(n)$, and find out why.

Comment: Why can't $d$ be $1$?

Comment: @lhf You are right. I should have thought that. Still thinking why d cant be 1.... :-( Any help ple

Comment: @DanielFischer I am not getting anywhere. The numbers are 15,36,50,57,78,85 and this means these number will share common factors with $n$. The common prime factors are 2,3,5,13,17. That means $n$ will be of the form $n=7^{a_1}2^{a_2}3^{a_3}5^{a_4}13^{a_5}17^{a_6}$. Here $a_1$ cannot be more than 1 because if not, then $(d, n/d)=1$ will not be satisfied as already we choose $d=7$ and $n\equiv 0[49]$ will yield $(d, n/d)=(7,n/7)\neq 1$. So $a_1=1$. 

$a_2=0$ because $8\in U_d(n)$. Now ??

Comment: Now $36$ and $50$ show that $3 \mid n$ and $5 \mid n$. Thus (assuming $d = 1$ has been ruled out) we have $105 \mid n$. And then it remains to find an argument that if $n$ were larger than $105$, then $U_7(n)$ would need to contain more than $8$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $8 \in U_d(n)$ it follows that $d \mid (8-1)$, hence $d \in \{1,7\}$. Now $(8,n)= 1$ implies $(2,n) = 1$, and of course $2 \equiv 1 \pmod{1}$, thus $2 \notin U_d(n)$ shows $d = 7$.

Next, $36 \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$ and $36 \notin U_7(n)$ shows $(36,n) > 1$. Since $2 \nmid n$ we further conclude $(9,n) > 1$, i.e. $3 \mid n$. Similarly, $50 \notin U_7(n)$ yields $5 \mid n$, and altogether $105 \mid n$.

Finally, note that $U_d(n)$ is a subgroup of $U(n)$, and its index is $\varphi(d)$. Hence in our situation we have
$$\varphi(n) = \varphi(7)\cdot \operatorname{card} U_7(n) = 6\cdot 8 = \varphi(105)\,.$$
The only multiples of $105$ with $\varphi(n) = 48$ are $105$ and $210$, and the oddness of $n$ then yields $n = 105$. (And one easily verifies that $U_7(105)$ is indeed the given set.)

Comment: So beautiful solution. However, the second line I am still having some confusion. Would you mind to elaborate more? I mean I did realize why (2,n)=1. But why does that with $2\equiv 1(mod 1)$ would suggest $d\neq 1$ ?

Comment: By definition $U_d(n) = \{ r \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leqslant r \leqslant n, (r,n) = 1, r \equiv 1 \pmod{d}\}$. Since $r \equiv 1 \pmod{1}$ is satisfied for all $r \in \mathbb{Z}$ it follows that $U_1(n) = U(n) = \{ r \in \mathbb{N} : 1 \leqslant r \leqslant n, (r,n) = 1\}$. Thus $2 \in U_1(n)$ for every odd $n > 1$.

Comment: Ohho, now its clear. Truly it was a deep insight of yours. Cool :-)