# Finding out $n$ and $d$ so that $U_d(n)$ will be given set.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

This is a post related to somehow [this one which I posted earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791748/find-n-d-for-u-dn/3791870#3791870). In this post the problem is solved so nicely, however, I am unable to utilize the same idea in this current situation.

Suppose $n$ is a positive integer and $d$ is its positive divisor. If $U(n)$ be the collection of all positive integers less than or equal to $n$ and coprime to $n$ and
$$U_d(n)=\{x\in \mathbb{N}: x\equiv 1\pmod{d}\}$$
how to find $n,d$ such that
$$U_d(n)=\{1,13,25,37\}$$
would hold ?

Clearly here $d$ is divisor of gcd of $1-1,13-1,25-1,37-1$ i.e. $12$. So $d=1,2,3,4,6,12$. How to show $d$ is $12$ only? In the above problem there were only two values 1 and 7. However here we are getting composite divisor as well.

Once we show that, how to find $n$ then?

Basically what I am searching for a general approach if there be any. Can someone help me out on this, please?

**Post Work**

After getting hints and suggestions ( thanks to both Erik Wong and cgss) I am trying to solve this problem as much as I can.

By Erik's answer, now I understand why $d=12$ only. Therefore $U_d(n)$ becomes now $U_{12}(n)$. Moreover, $12$ must divide $n$ and $n>37$ and each member of $U_{12}(n)$  must be of the form $12k+1$. However $25\in U_{12}(n)$ which means $25\in U(n)$ and so $(25,n)=1$ implying $(5,n)=1$. Thus $n$ must be 5 free.

We consider then, $$n=2^{a_1}3^{a_2}.m$$ where $a_1\geqslant 2, a_2\geqslant 1, m\in \mathbb{N}$ with $(2.3.5, m)=1$. Then
$$U_{12}(n)\simeq U\left(\frac{n}{12}\right)=U(2^{a_1-2}3^{a_2-1}m)$$ iff $(12, \frac{n}{12})=1$. This suggests that $a_1-2=0, a_2-1=0$ i.e. $a_1=2, a_2=1$ so that $n$ reduces to $n=2^2 3^1 m$.

Therefore
\begin{align*}
&|U_{12}(n)|=|U(2^0 3^0 m)|\\
\Rightarrow &4=\varphi(m)
\end{align*}

*[The actual answers are $n=48, d=12$. Which means we now have to show $m=1$ in the above equation. The solution of $\varphi(m)=4$ are $m\in \{5,8,10,12\}$
But how can we show here $m=1$?]*

Comment: You have asked a similar question today. Refrain from doing that without mentioning the reason behind it.

Comment: I know what i already post. However in the current problem i could not utilize the same argument and got stuck. Had it been so easier for me to get the ans, i did not have to post here  since i couldnot get any help from others

Comment: Assume that $d=4$. But then why $5$ isn't in the set? Because it wasn't coprime with $n$ in the first place. But then how is $25$ in the set?

Comment: @Anjan3 The point is not that you can’t post similar questions.  You can, but it is impolite to do so without linking to the related question and explaining why the new question merits asking.  Withholding such detail wastes the time of the volunteers on this site: they shouldn’t have to chase down your other questions to discover context that you already know.

Comment: @ErickWong You are right. I agree with you. I must have keep that in my mind. I apologize. But honestly speaking I am really helpless as having no idea how shall I establish that d is 12 only, not any thing else. and after that how to get n. I tried to use the idea of the previous post but somehow felt it is not connecting :-(

Comment: @Anjan3 I trust you are being sincere in your efforts, so thank you. I’ll try to write up a partial answer (some details that I think you can fill in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a much lengthier answer without the assumption that $d \mid n$, which admits a fair number of solutions.  Exploiting this constraint gives us a significant amount of structure, namely that $U_d(n)$ is a subgroup of the group of units $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$.

Since $U_d(n)$ has 4 elements, every element has order dividing $4$.  Hence $n$ must divide both $13^4 - 1$ and $25^4 - 1$, whose gcd is 48.  Since $n \ge 37$, it must be exactly $48$.  We easily conclude that $d=12$ once we know $n$.

Comment: OMG !!! You just nailed it :-D. Cleanshot bullseye!!!!

Answer (score 1):

First we’ll try to rule out smaller values of $d$.  They each fall in one of the two categories $d \mid 4$ and $d \mid 6$ (these two cases correspond to the two prime factors of $12$).

Suppose $d \mid 4$: then the fact that $U_d(n)$ doesn’t contain $5$ must be because $n$ is divisible by $5$, but then this contradicts $25 \in U_d(n)$.

Suppose $d \mid 6$: then the fact that $U_d(n)$ doesn’t contain $7, 19, 31$ must be because $n$ is divisible by all those primes.  But then $n > 169 = 13^2$, so in order to avoid $U_d(n)$ containing $169$ we need $n$ to be divisible by $13$, contradicting $13 \in U_d(n)$.

Now that we are assured $d=12$, there are a number of valid choices of $n$, and some amount of case-checking is unavoidable.  Firstly, in the range $37 \le n < 49$, all values of $n$ should work except for those divisible by exclusionary primes $5,13,37$.

Once we check values of $n \ge 49$, we need only consider $7 \mid n$.  Up to $n < 61$, this is also sufficient to exclude the only $12k+1$ number $49$ that causes trouble.

After $n \ge 61$, we need $7 \cdot 61 \mid n$.  But this forces $n \ge 169$, and as above we know that this is impossible because $13 \in U_d(n)$.

The general principle in both parts of this argument (isolating $d$ and then $n$) is that exclusions due to non-coprimality tend to yield larger and larger lower bounds for $n$, and eventually force $[1,n]$ to contain a number composed only of primes that we know something about.

Comment: I tried to move forward. Your insight is really beautiful. Can you please see my attempt that made just now in the question ?

Comment: Oh I did not notice that $d \mid n$ is an additional constraint!  My solution is for the more general scenario without such requirement. I think a simpler approach is possible without it.